# My obfuscates not work?

Tags: android, obfuscation

I try make obfuscate to my android code but when I try decompile my `.Dex` file after export my project to .Apk, I found all my `class` and `field` name not changed.
I read article from developer.android and enable my Enabling `ProGuard` but obfuscate not work.
Contents of my `proguard.cfg`:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

contents of `project.properties`:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-16
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this line:

```
....proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

and compare to the file name you mentioned above

> my `proguard.cfg`

Seems that it doesn't match. Try renaming the file to `proguard-project.txt`.

***p.s.:*** check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html); alternatively you could change the entry to

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard.cfg
```

Take care that the proguard file is in the project's root directory or add the path to it as well.